# How to annotate a method that returns a specific type (or subtype)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please consider this snippet of python 3.5 code:

```
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
   pass

class AbstractSomething: 

    def get_foobinator_type(self):  
        return Foo
```

I'd like to annotate ([using PEP-0484 annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) return value of `get_foobinator_type` method to say: "It returns a type, that is either a `Foo` or any subtype of it".

I din't find any sensible way to do it in Python. Here are approaches that are obviously wrong:

- Following: `def get_foobinator_type(self) -> Foo` means that this method returns an **instance** of `Foo`.
- Following: `def get_foobinator_type(self) -> type` means that this method returns a type, but sadly, there is no information about that this is needs to be a subtype of `Foo`.

In Java terms I'd like to have method with signature like: `Class<Foo> getFoobinatorType()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lately (in Python `3.5.2`) a generic `Type` was introduced, so solution is:

```
class AbstractSomething: 

    def get_foobinator_type(self) -> typing.Type[Foo]:  
        return Bar
```

See: [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you really cannot. You're looking for a way to indicate the return *type* of a **class**; to check based on what the type of the class is, i.e its metaclass.

The problem with that is that a metaclass doesn't help a type checker evaluate what the inheritance of an object might be, if it's of type `type` it's alright.

Apart from that, and, not being sure what type-checker you use, `mypy` for example [doesn't have support yet](https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Unsupported-Python-Features) for custom metaclasses which you might use to group your objects in a more custom group.

The way I see it, you either don't annotate at all all, or, you change the implementation and annotate with `Foo`.

Comment: I strongly suspected that this is the case. I don't use static type checker, I use type hints mostly to document API's and to make code-completion better.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is TypeVar from the typing module.

```
from typing import TypeVar

class Foo:
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
   pass

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Foo)

class AbstractSomething: 

    def get_foobinator_type(self) -> T:  
        return Foo
```

[From the documentation of typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

> Alternatively, a type variable may specify an upper bound using
>   bound=. This means that an actual type substituted (explicitly
>   or implicitly) for the type variable must be a subclass of the
>   boundary type, see PEP 484